# txtProgressBar not updating on Mac R Console

Tags: r, macos, progress-bar

My R (3.0.2) console doesn't update a `txtProgressBar` until all the code has executed (defeating the purpose of a progress bar). I've been running the following:

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(0, 20, 0)
for (i in 1:20) {
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
```

Nothing is output for 10 seconds (the time to execute the whole code segment) and then the entire progress bar is printed out. This behavior doesn't change if I add a `flush.console()` call after the `setTxtProgressBar` call.

I suspect this is Mac R console-specific, as the progress bar works as expected in the linux R console. How can I get the expected progress bar behavior?

Comment: I can confirm it also works as expected with both R 3.0.2 and R 3.1.0 on Win 8.1, from the R terminal, RGui, and RStudio.

Comment: Works fine for me on OSX 10.9.3 with R 3.1.0

Comment: Hardly worth an answer -- Since `R3.1` was a significant upgrade, anything running on a previous version is pretty much considered abandoned.